# Using knn to predict values from another DataFrame (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, knn, predict

I created a DataFrame with geological data from a well log, then I created a new column to label each row with a name according to its differents properties. That means: each row now has a rock name.

My question: I already trained my first DataFrame with all the data that I have and now I want to predict the labels (rock names) of a new DataFrame that has the same columns (properties) of the first one. But I do not know how to do it. Here is my code till now:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

data = pd.read_excel('wellA.xlsx')            #size (20956,26)
well1 = pd.concat([data['GR'], data['NPHI'], data['RHOB'], data['SW'], 
data['VSH'], data['rock_name']], axis=1, keys = 
['GR','NPHI','RHOB','SW','VSH','rock_name'])
well1 = well1.drop(well1.index[0:15167])
well1.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 9)
d = {'Claystone': 1, 'Calcareous Claystone': 2, 'Sandy Claystone': 3, 
'Limestone': 4, 'Muddy Limestone': 5, 'Muddy Sandstone': 6, 'Sandstone': 7}
well1['Label'] = well1['rock_name'].map(d)         #size (5412,7)

X = well1[well1.columns[:5]]         #size (5412, 5)
y = well1.rock_name                  #size (5412,)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (X, y, random_state = 0)
#sizes: X_train(4059,5), X_test(1353,5) , y_train(4059,), y_test(1353,)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)      
knn.score(X_test, y_test) 

data2 = pd.read_excel('wellB.xlsx')        #size (29070, 12)
well2 = pd.concat([data2['GR'], data2['NPHI'], data2['RHOB'], data2['SW'], 
data2['VSH']], axis=1, keys = ['GR','NPHI','RHOB','SW','VSH'])
well2.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)         #size (2124, 5)

# values of the properties
gammaray = well2['GR'].values                             
neutron = well2['NPHI'].values
density = well2['RHOB'].values
swat = well2['SW'].values
vshale = well2['VSH'].values

rock_name_pred = knn.predict([[gammaray, neutron, density, swat, vshale]])
```

and then I have the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\laguiar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\laguiar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/laguiar/Desktop/Projeto Norne/exemploKNN.py", line 41, in 
<module> rock_name_pred = knn.predict([[gammaray, neutron, density, swat, 
vshale]])

File "C:\Users\laguiar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\neighbors\classification.py", line 143, in predict
X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')

File "C:\Users\laguiar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 451, in check_array
% (array.ndim, estimator_name))

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that KNN expects arrays with a dimension lower or equal to 2. However in your script, your properties, like `gammaray` are `numpy` arrays.
When you write `[[gammaray, neutron, density, swat, vshale]]`, in your `knn.predict` call, the double brackets add 2 dimensions so you end up with a 3-D array.
Try calling the `predict` method like this:
`rock_name_pred = knn.predict([gammaray, neutron, density, swat, vshale])`

Or you could call the `predict` method directly on your dataframe, just like the `fit` method:
`rock_name_pred = knn.predict(well2)`

Comment: Putting 'well2' in the predict method worked pretty well. Thanks, Luc!